# useRoute().params is empty on initial load but works after a refresh

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-router, nuxtjs3

Component #1 : contains a click function that pushes the new id in the route like so :

```
<template>
  <div class="p-4 flex ">

    <div>
        <img :src="author.profileImage" alt="" class="w-10 h-10 rounded-full" />

    </div>

    <div class="ml-3">
        <span class="font-medium text-gray-800 dark:text-white"> {{author.name}}</span>



        <span class="ml-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-400">
            <NuxtLink to="#">
                {{ author.handle }}
            </NuxtLink>

            . {{ props.tweet.postedAtHuman }}
        </span>


        <p v-if="props.tweet.replyTo" class="text-sm">

          <span class="text-gray-500">
            Replying to 
          </span> 
            <span  @click="doSomething(replyToTweetUrl)" class="text-blue-400">
                {{ props.tweet.replyTo.author.handle }}
            </span>
        </p>
       
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  tweet: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
});

const author = props.tweet.author;
const { setTweetIdUrl ,tweetIdUrl } = useUrls();
  console.log(props.tweet.replyTo?.id)


const replyToTweetUrl = computed(() => `/status/${props.tweet.replyTo?.id}`)

const router = useRouter();

async function doSomething(replyToTweetUrl) {

  console.log("ldsùfez  "+tweetIdUrl.value)
  tweetIdUrl.value = replyToTweetUrl
  console.log("ldsùfez 2  "+tweetIdUrl.value)

  await router.push(replyToTweetUrl);

}

</script>
```

Component #2 is status/[id].vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <MainSection title="Tweet" :loading="loading">
      <Head>
        <Title> </Title>
      </Head>
      <TweetDetails :user="user" :tweet="tweet"/>
    </MainSection>

   
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const loading = ref(false);
const { getTweetById } = useTweets();
const tweet = ref(null);


async function getTweet() {
  loading.value = true;
  try {
      // Use nextTick to ensure the DOM is updated
      await nextTick();

    //const response = await getTweetById(getTweetIdFromRoute());


    const tweetId = useRoute().params.id;
    const response = await getTweetById(tweetId);
    tweet.value = response.tweet;
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    loading.value = false;
  }
}

const {useAuthUser} = useAuth()
const user = useAuthUser()

onBeforeMount(() => {
  getTweet();
});
</script>
```

I need to get the id from the route right after clicking the link to that route but instead , it is returning an empty object  on the first load (The whole useRoute is empty) unless i manually refresh the page , any idea what the problem could be ? please help !

Answer (score 1):

useRoute should only be used inside setup context (i.e. the created hook of the component).

```js
<script setup>
const tweetId = useRoute().params.id;

async function getTweet() { 
// can use tweetId here
...
}
```

Also, there's a better lifecycle hook to use than `onBeforeMounted` if you're using code like this:

```js
// Use nextTick to ensure the DOM is updated
await nextTick();
```

You're basically awaiting for `mounted` hook to occur, which is the hook that occurs after the DOM is rendered. So just use `mounted` hook

Comment: Thank you for your answer , form some reasons it didn't work for me i tried it before , but i was able to get away with the issue by using Composables and a state variable where i stored the id and made it accessible across the app ,  i am not sure if it is a good practice to do so though .